Using the :around-compile argument to asdf:defsystem
To better understand how :around-compile works, I would like to track (ie, printout) which component file is currently being compiled.
The ASDF Manual seems to imply that the value can be a lambda expression with one argument--eg, (lambda (next) ... (funcall next ...) ...)--which will call ASDF's compile-file* function, which can take the arguments (input-file &rest keys &key compile-check output-file warnings-file emit-cfasl &allow-other-keys). The Manual also says the around-compile hook may supply additional keyword arguments to pass to that call to compile-file*, which I assume refers to items like the input-file. Is it available from next? For example, a simple case might do something like:
(defsystem :project
  ...
  :around-compile (lambda (next)
                    (format t "~&Compiling ~A" input-file)
                    (funcall next))
  ...)

Is this on the right track? And could this also be done with the :perform keyword? Thanks for any insights.

This is something that would work (thunk corresponds to your next):
(asdf:defsystem "$PROJECT_NAME"
  :description "A simple ASDF system with custom compilation messages"
  :version "0.1"
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "src/file1")
               (:file "src/file2"))
  :around-compile (lambda (thunk)
                    ;; Before compilation
                    (format t "Doing something before compilation..")
                      (let ((result (funcall thunk)))
                        ;; After compilation
                        (format t "Doing something after compilation.. ~A~%" result)
                        result)))

This bash script generates my-system, an example package.
You need uiop::*compile-file-pathname* to be able to refer to the compiled file's path.
I left out the part which would actually tell asdf to use the current folder as a project folder. Therefore, you have to generate this bash script only within your ~/quicklisp/local-projects/ folder, so that
asdf can easily find the project for loading.
Therefore you do:
cd ~/quicklisp/local-projects/
nano build-my-system.sh

and enter as its content:
#!/bin/bash

# Define the project name and directory
PROJECT_NAME="my-system"
PROJECT_DIR="$(pwd)/$PROJECT_NAME"

# Create the directory structure
echo "Creating directory structure..."
mkdir -p "$PROJECT_DIR/src"

# Create the system definition file (my-system.asd)
echo "Creating $PROJECT_NAME.asd..."
cat <<EOF > "$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME.asd"
(asdf:defsystem "$PROJECT_NAME"
  :description "A simple ASDF system with custom compilation messages"
  :version "0.1"
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "src/file1")
               (:file "src/file2"))
  :around-compile (lambda (thunk)
                    ;; Before compilation
                    (format t "Doing something before compilation..")
                      (let ((result (funcall thunk)))
                        ;; After compilation
                        (format t "Doing something after compilation.. ~A~%" result)
                        result)))
EOF

# Create source file 1 (src/file1.lisp)
echo "Creating src/file1.lisp..."
cat <<EOF > "$PROJECT_DIR/src/file1.lisp"
(defun hello ()
  (format t "Hello from file1!~%"))
EOF

# Create source file 2 (src/file2.lisp)
echo "Creating src/file2.lisp..."
cat <<EOF > "$PROJECT_DIR/src/file2.lisp"
(defun goodbye ()
  (format t "Goodbye from file2!~%"))
EOF

# Create a README.md file (optional)
echo "Creating README.md..."
cat <<EOF > "$PROJECT_DIR/README.md"
# My System

This is a simple Common Lisp system with custom compile-time messages using ASDF.
EOF


# Build the system using SBCL
echo "Building the system with SBCL..."
sbcl --eval "(asdf:load-system \"$PROJECT_NAME\")" --eval "(hello)" --eval "(goodbye)" --quit

echo "Build complete!"

and run the script with:
bash build-my-system.sh

And then it will generate my-system with its folder and files with lisp code.
And it will run sbcl and load my-system.
output:
% bash build-my-system.sh
Creating directory structure...
Creating my-system.asd...
Creating src/file1.lisp...
Creating src/file2.lisp...
Creating README.md...
Building the system with SBCL...
This is SBCL 2.4.6, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
Loading ~/.sbclrc...
Doing something before compilation..
; compiling file "/Users/josephus/quicklisp/local-projects/my-system/src/file1.lisp" (written 19 OCT 2024 08:16:17 AM):

; wrote /Users/josephus/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.4.6-macosx-arm64/Users/josephus/quicklisp/local-projects/my-system/src/file1-tmpGHU3ALSV.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.000
Doing something after compilation.. /Users/josephus/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.4.6-macosx-arm64/Users/josephus/quicklisp/local-projects/my-system/src/file1.fasl
Doing something before compilation..
; compiling file "/Users/josephus/quicklisp/local-projects/my-system/src/file2.lisp" (written 19 OCT 2024 08:16:17 AM):

; wrote /Users/josephus/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.4.6-macosx-arm64/Users/josephus/quicklisp/local-projects/my-system/src/file2-tmpAAURSO1.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.000
Doing something after compilation.. /Users/josephus/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.4.6-macosx-arm64/Users/josephus/quicklisp/local-projects/my-system/src/file2.fasl
Hello from file1!
Goodbye from file2!
Build complete!

For windows users, you create a powershell file within your quicklisp/local-projects/ folder
with the filename: build-my-system.ps1
# Define the project name and directory
$ProjectName = "my-system"
$ProjectDir = Join-Path (Get-Location) $ProjectName

# Create the directory structure
Write-Host "Creating directory structure..."
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$ProjectDir\src" -Force

# Create the system definition file (my-system.asd)
Write-Host "Creating $ProjectName.asd..."
@"
(asdf:defsystem "$PROJECT_NAME"
  :description "A simple ASDF system with custom compilation messages"
  :version "0.1"
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "src/file1")
               (:file "src/file2"))
  :around-compile (lambda (thunk)
                    ;; Before compilation
                    (format t "Doing something before compilation..")
                      (let ((result (funcall thunk)))
                        ;; After compilation
                        (format t "Doing something after compilation.. ~A~%" result)
                        result)))
"@ | Out-File "$ProjectDir\$ProjectName.asd" -Encoding UTF8

# Create source file 1 (src/file1.lisp)
Write-Host "Creating src/file1.lisp..."
@"
(defun hello ()
  (format t "Hello from file1!~%"))
"@ | Out-File "$ProjectDir\src\file1.lisp" -Encoding UTF8

# Create source file 2 (src/file2.lisp)
Write-Host "Creating src/file2.lisp..."
@"
(defun goodbye ()
  (format t "Goodbye from file2!~%"))
"@ | Out-File "$ProjectDir\src\file2.lisp" -Encoding UTF8

# Create a README.md file (optional)
Write-Host "Creating README.md..."
@"
# My System

This is a simple Common Lisp system with custom compile-time messages using ASDF.
"@ | Out-File "$ProjectDir\README.md" -Encoding UTF8

# Build the system using SBCL
Write-Host "Building the system with SBCL..."
sbcl --eval "(asdf:load-system \"$ProjectName\")" --eval "(hello)" --eval "(goodbye)" --quit

Write-Host "Build complete!"

and run it from there with:
./build-my-system.ps1

I hope this works, because I didn't test the windows powershell script.
But the bash scripts worked on my mac.

When I tested this on an existing project using SBCL in Windows, it seems uiop:compile-file-pathname always returns NIL. This is not surprising, since the manual specifically says the compilation is done by ASDF's compile-file* function. So compile-file* is evidently called during (funcall thunk), which returns the compiled file. This allows arbitrary statements to appear before or after the funcall, which is what I was uncertain about. Thanks.

In deed, if you check in the REPL uiop::*compile-file-pathname* you get NIL. True.

@davypough Thanks for the comment!
I corrected the answer and output. The (funcall thunk) returns the compile-file-pathname actually. As you see in the corrected version of the answer.
